# How can I add a carriage return in a text using regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text file with multiple lines. I'll try to set a pattern to add a new carriage return in some lines of the text. This lines are like that:

*lorem ipsum.

dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [FIS] Donec feugiat*

Well, the pattern is a line followed by other which has some characters and a '[' character too. If '[' is not present the pattern fails and the carriage return hasn't be added.

How can I do it using regular expressions??

I'm using C# as programming language and regex engine too.

Comment: The response to my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767869/how-to-regex-replace-match-group-item-with-method-result

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a line break after a . then you just replace it with itself and a line break. To make sure it is the last character, use a lookahead to check it is followed by whitespace, i.e. `(?=\s)`

So, to replace with newline character (recommended for most situations):

```
replace( input , '\.(?=\s)' , '\.\n' )
```

If you *must* use carriage return (and there are very few places that *require* it, even on Windows), you can simply add one:

```
replace( input , '\.(?=\s)' , '\.\r\n' )
```

If you want to ensure that a . is always followed by two line breaks, and not cause extra line breaks if they are already want, then it gets a little more complex, and required a negative lookahead, but looks like this:

```
replace( input , '\.(?!\S)(?:\r?\n){0,2}' , '\.\r\n\r\n' )
```

Because regex engines default to greedy, the `{0,2}` will try to match twice, then once, then zero times - at which point the negative lookahead for a non-space makes sure it is actually the end of a word.

(If you might have more than two newlines and want to reduce to two, you can just use `{0,}` instead, which has `*` as a shortcut notation.)

It's probably worth pointing out that none of the above will consume any spaces/tabs - if this is desired the lookaheads can either be changed from `(?=\s)` to `\s+`, you could can do a second replace of `\n[ \t]+` with `\n` to remove any leading spaces/tabs, or something similar, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, good explanation. But I have to include if next line some characters and '['. If this rule is Ok then it has to be added '\r\n'. Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to *avoid* adding the newline if a `[` is found? If so, the middle example can be updated to `\.(?=\s++[^\[])` - assuming your regex engine supports possessive quantifiers anyway - which flavour of regex are you using this with?

Comment: I use it on C#. I'll test it and tell you if it was fine.

Comment: @jaloplo: can you do us a favor and update your question to include _all_ your requirements? This way it gets scattered through the comments little by little and that's rather hard to follow.

Comment: @Peter: apparently jaloplo uses C#, I added the tag. Currently, .NET does not support them (mainly PCRE and Java http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html do support it).

Comment: Ah, but .NET *does* support atomic grouping, which is the long-winded equivalent, so that `\s++` becomes `(?>\s+)` and it should otherwise work the same.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use \r for carriage return and \n for new line

Answer (score 2):

What flavor? Here it's done for C#:

```
string yourString = @"el tiempo.
campo vectorial vector field. [FIS] Campo ";
string newString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "el tiempo.", "$0\r\n");  // just \n may be sufficient though
```

EDIT: the above is an answer to the original question. After the excellent answer by Peter Boughton, I don't need to add much. Well, perhaps this, a little regex without look-around assertions, will simply replace all dots followed by one or more newlines with two newlines.

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"\.(\r|\n)+", ".\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: Please, could you be more generic??? Imagine that "el tiempo." is any text that '.' is its last character.

Comment: jaloplo, if you want more generic you should state this in the question. You also haven't specified if there should be a linebreak added in the "field. [FIS]" part.

Comment: I think this was obvious, but I apologize about it. I'll try to be more specific in next questions.

Comment: I don't have the "rights" to edit questions, but for us and future visitors, can you update the q. with: 1) the programming language, 2) the pattern in English words? Even though there's a good answer meanwhile, it'll help others if questions are clear :)