# Regex.Replace: Conditional replacement based on optional group

Tags: c#, regex

I am using Regex.Replace in C#. In the replaced string, I want to put a condition that part of the string only comes out if one of the optional group is captured. For example, I have this regex:-

```
(?<Expiry>\d+[my])\s+(?<Flag>[a-z][A-Z])?\s*$)
```

Note that `Flag` captured group is *optional*.

The replacement string is

```
"Expiry is ${Expiry}. Flag is : ${Flag}"
```

Now I want `"Flag is : ${Flag}"` string only appear in the result if the Flag group is captured.

I am using following code:

```
var regex = new
Regex("(?<Expiry>\d+[my])\s+(?<Flag>[a-z][A-Z])?\s*$)",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
string result = regex.Replace("10y", "Expiry is ${Expiry}. Flag is : ${Flag}";
```

Result should by `Expiry is 10y`.

```
string result = regex.Replace("10y abc", "Expiry is ${Expiry}. Flag is ${Flag}");
```

Result should be "Expiry is 10y. Flag is : abc".

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some of you current code?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767869/how-to-regex-replace-match-group-item-with-method-result

Comment: Please take a moment to acquaint yourself with the editor. There is a code formatting command (Ctrl-K) that you should use if you post code, otherwise markdown will interpret `*` (and others), changing the meaning of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use different replacement values based on whether the specified group participated in the match (=matched)  or not.

See the example below:

```
var s = "1m aZ";
var pat = @"(?<Expiry>\d+[my])\s+(?<Flag>[a-z][A-Z])?\s*$";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, pat, m => m.Groups["Flag"].Success ? 
    string.Format("Flag is : {0}.", m.Groups["Flag"].Value) : 
    string.Format("Expiry is {0}.", m.Groups["Expiry"].Value));
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/sgThav)

If `Flag` group matches, the replacement will be `string.Format("Flag is : {0}.", m.Groups["Flag"].Value)`, else, the replacement will only contain the expiry message.